# How to access data from Fragments in FragmentActivity for swipe prevention usage

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-fragmentactivity

I'm following the [BitMapFun](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip) tutorial from the android developer docs. As I'm a total newby to Android/Java programming in general.

I have created a custom ImageViewer (called **TouchImageView**) which allows the user to zoom, doubletap, etc... and applied it on the **ImageDetailFragment** class.

In the **TouchImageView** class I have a **boolean variable that can detect if the User zoomed in** or not, and in the case it's zoomedIn it will also flag if the image is at the border side. (Thus the zoomedIn bit and the border of the screen matters)

I want apply this logic to enable or disable the ViewPager to allow the user to scroll to the next/previous page (read Fragment) This ViewPager is located in the **ImageDetailActivity** that implements the **FragmentActivity**

As my code is now, if I move left or right (in the zoomed in state) instead of moving the image, it will go to the next Fragment instead of scrolling left or right. Unless I firstly move up or down, where I can then scroll the image.

So I thought, if I have a boolean in the Fragment that I can check to in order for my Activiy to enable/disable the ViewPager then I can 'control' the way the scroll works.

Is this logic correct? and if so, how can I retrieve the boolean from the Fragment in my DetailActivity class. I have tried doing it with an Interface, however I'm getting always a false reply back (due to the initalization of fragments during the onCreate?) So I need something that can retrieve that boolean during run-time on the displayed fragment. However from my code below it's never working.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 .... Do stuff like fetching images and caching etc ....
 mPager = (ScrollViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
 mAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), imgs.getImagesLocal().length);
 mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setPageMargin((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_detail_pager_margin));
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    mPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //v.mAdapter.mCurItem
            ScrollViewPager scroll = (ScrollViewPager) v;
            //Log.d(TAG, "-----------------Current pos is "+ scroll.getCurrentItem());
            ImageDetailFragment frag = (ImageDetailFragment) mAdapter.getItem(scroll.getCurrentItem());
            if(frag.isPageChangeable())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "-----------------Page is zoomed");
            }else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "----------------------Page is not Zoomed");
            }
            return false;

        }
    });
}
```

The Fragment initialization that I got is.

```
/**
 * The main adapter that backs the ViewPager. A subclass of FragmentStatePagerAdapter as there could be a large number of items in the ViewPager and we don't want to retain
 * them all in memory at once but create/destroy them on the fly.
 */
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final int mSize;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
        super(fm);
        mSize = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ImageDetailFragment.newInstance(imgs.getImagesLocal()[position], position, imgs.getImagesLocal().length);
    }
}
```

If you want to take a look at the full code you can [download it here.](http://elfredo.be/ImageGridActivity.zip)

For the prevention of the swipe/fling I thought of using the following information found on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918581/android-fragmentactivity-and-prevent-swipe)

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution, whiiii!

I implemented the [Disable ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814017/disable-viewpager) as mentioned in the link.
Then added the following in the onClick method.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    TouchImageViewLocal ti = (TouchImageViewLocal) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    if(ti.isZoomed()){
        Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------------------------is zoomed in? " + ti.isZoomed());
        mPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
    }else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------------------------is zoomed in? " + ti.isZoomed());
        mPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
    }
```

This allows the screen if it's zoomed in to stop/start the swipe, however, I still have to find the on edge detection. :-)